# Mathematica: finding Extrema positions with Solve, Reduce and FindRoot. (derivative)

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, derivative

I want to determinate the local maxima and minima of the following 2 functions

1. `xE[t_] := 10 (t - Sin[t]) - Sqrt[40^2 - (10 (1 - Cos[t]))^2]`
2. `vE = xE'[t]`

So I tried to solve the first derivate of `xE[t]` with:

```
extremaXE = Solve[vE[t] == 0, t] (* vE is the 1st derivative of xE *)
```

but I got this error:

```
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not 
be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
```

I tried then with reduce and I got this error:

```
Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce
```

so what should I do to determinate the local minima and maxima through the derivatives?

Comment: The functions have many maxima and minima, you could use `FindRoot` together with an initial guess.

Comment: Also notice from the Help : `Solve` deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations.

Comment: The [mathematica.se] site is in public beta, if you have further questions, you're likely to get good answers there.

Answer (score 0):

Use NLOpt.

It has algorithms to find local/global extrema with/without derivatives.
It is callable from C, C++, Fortran, Matlab or GNU Octave, Python, GNU Guile, and GNU R.

http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt

Does this help?

Comment: The OP wanted to know how to do it in Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get an error with `Reduce`. For example, to find the local extrema of `xE` I tried

```
Reduce[xE'[t] == 0, t]
```

which returned

```
C[1] \[Element] Integers && (t == 2 \[Pi] C[1] || 
   t == 2 I ArcTanh[2/Sqrt[3]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1])
```

Note that this gives you both real and complex solutions. If you only want the real ones you can try

```
Reduce[xE'[t] == 0, t, Reals]
```

which gives

```
C[1] \[Element] Integers && t == 2 \[Pi] C[1]
```

**Edit**

To substitute the solutions back into the original expression you could convert it to a list of rules using for example `ToRules`. Since `ToRules` can't handle expressions like `C[1] \[Element] Integers` we simplify the solution first

```
sol = Reduce[xE'[t] == 0, t];
sol = Simplify[sol, C[_] \[Element] Integers]

(* ==> t == 2 \[Pi] C[1] || t == 2 I ArcTanh[2/Sqrt[3]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] *)
```

`ToRules` will then convert this expression to a list of rules which you can substitute back into your expression using `ReplaceAll`

```
xE[t] /. {ToRules[sol]}

(* ==> {-Sqrt[1600 - 100 (1 - Cos[2 \[Pi] C[1]])^2] + 
          10 (2 \[Pi] C[1] - Sin[2 \[Pi] C[1]]), 
        -Sqrt[1600 - 100 (1 - Cosh[2 ArcTanh[2/Sqrt[3]] - 2 I \[Pi] C[1]])^2] + 
          10 (2 I ArcTanh[2/Sqrt[3]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] - 
          I Sinh[2 ArcTanh[2/Sqrt[3]] - 2 I \[Pi] C[1]])} *)
```

Note that the resulting expression still contains the constant `C[1]`. To find the extrema for a particular value of `C[1]` you can use another replacement rule, e.g.

```
({t, xE[t]} /. {ToRules[sol]}) /. {C[1] -> -4}
```

Comment: Danke Heike!! and then how to replace it to get the point with {t/.xE[t]} /. extremaXE ?

Comment: @ZelelB I've expanded my answer a bit to answer your question.